# When referring to multiple pieces of art, should I use the plural or singular form of "commission"?

Tags: grammatical-number

If someone commissioned an artist to draw more than one picture for them, should those pictures be collectively referred to as one "commission", or should they be called "commissions"?

"This commission was drawn by X." vs "These commissions were drawn by X."

Comment: Either; it doesn't matter.

Comment: May we have some complete examples? 'The client commissioned the artist to paint a picture…' or '…carve two statues…' or '…weave some tapestries…'?

I don't move in the art world yet 'This commission was drawn by…' sounds like a contrived variant of 'This drawing was commissioned by…' and either way, there is no indication whether 'This drawing' was at the time or is now to be considered by itself or as part of a collection, either artistically or commercially.

Answer (score 0):

"X was commissioned to make these drawings." The commission is the business arrangement, not the work of art.

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commission) sense 2b(b). The work produced by commission.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - OK, so it can mean the work, but I still find the OP's sentences unidiomatic.

Comment: "Commission" can certainly refer to the work, but it's awkward in this context, because the word focuses on the act of payment/request not the creative process. "This commission by Smith" could refer either to the patron or the artist, and therefore should be avoided. Even adding "painted" could confuse the casual reader who doesn't look at every word.

Comment: As do I. Stuart's correct about 'commission': I'd want 'If someone commissioned an artist to draw more than one picture for them, should that / those 'formal request/s to produce something (especially ... artistic work) in exchange for payment' [[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commission) sense 2b] be collectively referred to as one "commission", or should they be called "commissions"?' The answer is that it depends on whether one or two arrangements were made, and partly on whether, if two ... were made, the speaker notionally lumps them. Not my DV.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using it, the word "commission" refers, not to a request, but to a *work produced* on request; the requests weren't drawn, the drawings were. (Both senses are valid; see [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commission).)

Since there were multiple *works,* "commissions" is correct, even though they were all the result of a single request.